# Data.table replace sequence of values with NA

Tags: r, select, data.table, na

I want a specific sequence of values to be replaced by NA in a data table using a variable as column indicator.

```
Example:

    dt <- data.table(col1=1:10, col2=11:20)
    specific_column <- 2

Output: 
      col1 col2
 1:    1   11
 2:    2   12
 3:    3   13
 4:    4   14
 5:    5   15
 6:    6   16
 7:    7   17
 8:    8   18
 9:    9   19
10:   10   20
```

I want to specifically replace values with NA in col2 and position 2:5 to get the following output:

```
 col1 col2
 1:    1   11
 2:    2   NA
 3:    3   NA
 4:    4   NA
 5:    5   NA
 6:    6   16
 7:    7   17
 8:    8   18
 9:    9   19
10:   10   20
```

I am able to select the values I am interested in with:

```
   dt[2:5,..specific_column]
```

Unfortunately it is not possible to use the replacement method from data frames:

```
dt[2:5,..specific_column] <- NA
#Error in `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, 2:5, ..specific_column, value = NA) : 
  object '..specific_column' not found
```

The only work-around I found was:

```
dt[2:5,print(specific_column)] <- NA
```

This works, but as it always prints the "specific column" it slows down the progress by a lot.
(I am using a larger data set (10000rows, 28columns))

Is there a simple solution comparable to the one used for data frames?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
dt[2:5, (specific_column) := NA]
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! I tried it before but without () for specific_column

Answer (score 1):

there is a `set()` function in data.table

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(col1=1:10, col2=11:20)
specific_column <- 2L
set(DT, i=3:5, specific_column, NA)
DT
```

Answer (score 0):

From data.table version 1.14.3 (now in development), there is a new `env` argument for programmatic control of data.table calls (see [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#datatable-v1102--31-jan-2017)). Might be overkill for this simple situation, but I show how it would be used here because it is a potentially useful feature for more demanding situations, and therefore good to be aware of:

```
dt[2:5, mycol := NA, env = list(mycol = specific_column)]
```

Note, you can install the latest development version using `data.table::update.dev.pkg()`